# Django admin change_list.html error

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I recently changed my model and my sqlite3 database too.

When I run the server and go to my `admin/project/model` page. I get an error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'updated'.

Updated is a field in my model.

**models.py:**

```
@reversion.register
class Block(models.Model):      
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Request Blocks"
    inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, null=True) #limit_choices_to={'inventory_name': True})
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True) #unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='pending')
    derivatives = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)  
    subsystems = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    owners = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

admin.py:

```
class BlockAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    action_form = UpdateActionForm
    list_display = ['name', 'status', 'inventory', 'derivatives', 'added', 'updated'] #'block_date']
    list_filter = ['inventory', 'status', 'derivatives', ]
    search_fields = ['name']
    #list_per_page = 200
    ordering = ['name']
    actions = ['make_finalized', 'make_pending', 'move_to_inventory', 'block_current_date', 'export_csv', 'export_xls', 'export_xlsx']
```

**Error:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/inventory/block/

Django Version: 1.8.2
Python Version: 2.7.9


Template error:
In template /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-    py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'updated'

{% endif %}
 {% endblock %}

      <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
      {% if cl.formset %}
        <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>
      {% endif %}

      {% block result_list %}
          {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


      LINE 91{% result_list cl %}



          {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
      {% endblock %}
      {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}


Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/inventory/block/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'updated'
```

**Traceback:**

> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>     164.                 response = response.render() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/response.py"
>   in render
>     158.             self.content = self.rendered_content File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     135.         content = template.render(context, self._request) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/backends/django.py"
>   in render
>     74.         return self.template.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     209.                     return self._render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     201.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     79.             return node.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     135.         return compiled_parent._render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     201.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     79.             return node.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     135.         return compiled_parent._render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     201.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     79.             return node.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     135.         return compiled_parent._render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     201.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     79.             return node.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     79.             return node.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     79.             return node.render(context) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     1271.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py"
>   in result_list
>     320.             'results': list(results(cl))} File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py"
>   in results
>     296.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None)) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py"
>   in **init**
>     287.         super(ResultList, self).**init**(*items) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py"
>   in items_for_result
>     199.             f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/utils.py"
>   in lookup_field
>     288.         value = getattr(obj, name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py"
>   in **get**
>     598.                     qs = qs.filter(**params) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in filter
>     679.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in _filter_or_exclude
>     697.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs)) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in add_q
>     1304.         clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in _add_q
>     1332.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq, File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in build_filter
>     1203.             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in build_lookup
>     1096.                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/lookups.py"
>   in **init**
>     96.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/lookups.py"
>   in get_prep_lookup
>     134.         return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py"
>   in get_prep_lookup
>     727.             return self.get_prep_value(value) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8.2-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py"
>   in get_prep_value
>     985.         return int(value) Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/inventory/block/ Exception Value: invalid literal for int()
>   with base 10: 'updated'

Can anyone help with this error?

Comment: Did you migrate the database changes?

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Was the original `updated` field an integer? Seems like the error is complaining  about a `string` where `int()` was expected.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what is going on now, but I do not know why. This error occurs when i try to add the model field 'inventory' to my class BlockAdmin list_display. Any ideas on why and how this could be fixed?

Comment: I fixed it. Something was wrong with my db.

Comment: how did you fix it?